# Speed up training deep learning model in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am working with a training deep learning model with the Pytorch framework. And I add *torch.no_grad* to speed up the training phase

```
model.train()
for epoch in range(epochs):
  for data, label in loader:
     data, label = data.to(device), label.to(device)
     with torch.no_grad():
       out = model(data)
     out.requires_grad = True
     #model.zero_grad(), loss(), loss.backward, optim.step
```

The speed is improved, but have something wrong with the gradient update, the model doesn't converge correctly. Can someone explain to me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, when using the `torch.no_grad` context manager, the gradients are not computed, so the model cannot receive any update.

`torch.no_grad` is meant to be used in other cases, for example when evaluating the model. From the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html):

> Disabling gradient calculation is useful for inference, **when you are sure that you will not call `Tensor.backward()`**